# Flutter WebView keep logged in

Tags: flutter, cookies, webview

I'm trying to build an extremely simple hybrid app with flutter: it basically just connects to my website, that's it. All the functionalities I need are in the website itself.

I have a login system that allows users to "stay logged in" even when their session ends (the website is made with Flask by the way).

In my app, however, this works weirdly: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm thinking it could be something related to the fact that I have implemented a native back button feature (to go back to previusly visited page), but I have no idea what to do because the "keep logged in" feature works everywhere except for the app. (even google chrome on my phone works)

Here's my app:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  late WebViewController wv_controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: ()async{
          String? url = await wv_controller.currentUrl();

          if(url == "http://*mywebsite*/"){
            return true;
          } else {
            wv_controller.goBack();
            return false;
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: SafeArea(
              child: WebView(
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialUrl: "http://*mywebsite*/",

                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController wv){
                  wv_controller = wv;
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You may have to investigate how to keep sessions alive on the Android and iOS Webviews. As all flutter is doing is using those native webviews.

Comment: I have looked into Android's WebView, and it has a setting function `setDomStorageEnabled(bool)` that defaults to `false`. However Flutter does not give me this option and I also think this is not the problem since it sometimes remembers the session, other times it doesn't. It's almost like I need to visit a few other pages in the same website after login to keep the session alive when I reopen the app

Comment: Another update: I can confirm the problem is not `setDomStorageEnabled()` as Flutter automatically sets it to `true`.

Comment: I've had issues of this nature with `webviews` in the past. To be honest, my best solution was to rely on API token based authentication instead of web session based solutions. This allows you to just add your token - stored locally in your app - to your `HTTP` calls and ensure your user "session" is always alive.

Comment: @JoãoSoares thank you for the idea, I think it's the best solution. I've been looking at how to deal with this type of authentication both in my website and on the app, however I can't find a way to make flutter read response headers so that I can save the token in the app. Do you have a solution for this? I would like to avoid having to make a separate widget for login since I am very inexperienced with mobile development

Comment: You would have to make http calls to your API to get the token outside of the webview, just a normal api request. Then use that token in the headers on the webview requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and it at least retains data on Google websites that I'm navigating through using the WebView widget. It retains the login session even if I restarted the app. The WebViewController Javascript mode was set to `unrestricted`.

```dart
WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
```